# single method in getRequestDispatcher() in ServletRequest and ServletContext interfaces

Tags: java, servlets

HI
I like to know there is a single method called getRequestDispatcher() in ServletRequest and ServletContext interfaces. What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Servlet API Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29),

> The difference between this method [the ServletRequest one] and ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)  is that this method can take a relative path.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to link to the docs in the JavaEE specification, but the copy there says the same thing: http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a relative path to getRequestDispatcher() of ServletRequest but not to  getRequestDispatcher() of ServletContext.

**Example:**

My current request is served from page - *webapp/view/core/bar.jsp*
and requested page - *webapp/view/util/foo.jsp*

request.getRequestDispatcher("../util/foo.jsp") is valid and will be evaluated to the path relative to current request.

servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/view/util/foo.jsp") is valid and will evaluate from context root.

This is because ServletContext will not be aware of current request path.
If you decide to use '/' root to access your resources, then both ways are same.